# F12 developer tools in IE9 not loading style tab information for dynamic content

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I'm working on IE 7 and 8 HTML/CSS fixes, but when I use the Developer Tools and try to look at dynamically loaded HTML you first can't select the newly added elements, but then I read that you should hit the refresh in the toolbar which works. But, when you inspect any of the elements the style information in the style tab doesn't show properly.

All it shows is something like the following: 
inherited - html
inherited - body
inerhited - div
inerhited - div
inerhited - div

You can't expand these to see the actual attributes and values like you would with elements that aren't dynamically loaded.

Is there a workaround for this?

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 3):

There is.

It's a dirty workaround but should allow you to inspect elements that may have been added to the dom dynamically.

See the screenshot below:

[image: Select element and edit buttons]

If you can't pick an element (arrow button), click the edit button (with pencil) and you'll enter edit mode.  Click edit again to exit edit mode and the elements should now be selectable.

> **"Edit mode"**
>
> [image: Edit mode]

*Sometimes entering and exiting edit mode may leave have side effects but this technique works in most scenarios.*

Comment: Confirming: the disadvantage in question is still present in IE10. And the solution of @Phil does help there.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this problem myself.

I use an extended version of [Head.js](http://headjs.com/) to load stylesheet links as well as script files. I now have a specific IE8 styling bug that I need to investigate, but the dynamically added styles don't appear in the Developer Tools.

To debug it I think I'm going to have to temporarily add the css files statically. Chrome and Firefox dev tools handle this dynamic styling ok. That's fine if I have generic styling issue, but when it's IE specific I've got to jump through some hoops.

I can't think of a "solution" to this. Unfortunately we are at the mercy of the IE dev tools. Maybe IE 10 dev tools are better, but I'm on Windows 7 for now.

Comment: Well hopefully we find something to sort this out because it makes very difficult to do our jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried FireBug lite? This is a version of FireBug that is written completely using JavaScript and it allows you to use most of the usual firebug features but in IE. It works in IE 6 and later.

I've used it successfully in the past when debugging on the iPad where, until iOS 6, there was no way to inspect the HTML. It works equally well on IE.

You can read more about it here: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite